# this trip is overnight?

Tags: adjectives, predicative-complement, attributives

It's grammatically correct to say *this overnight trip* but is it possible to say *This trip is overnight*?

And what is the difference between

*It happened overnight.*

*It happened over the night.*

Answer (score 2):

**Overnight** is an idiom meaning **through the night**

> This trip is **overnight**

is correct and understandable, but natives would usually say

> This is an **overnight** trip.
>
> The train leaving London Euston to Edinburgh Waverly leaving at midnite is the **overnight** train.
>   Flying New York to London is usually an **overnight** flight.
>   Travelling all night may be referred to as an ***overnighter***

is also correct.

> If you are on an ***overnighter*** and stay awake and can't sleep, you have **pulled an** ***allnighter***.

Your other sentence

> It happened **over the night**

is not correct since things do not happen **over** or **under** (physical placement) a night

> It happened **over the course of the night**
>
> **Over the course of the night** the Moon and planets rise and fall in the sky.

is correct.  This notion is usually expressed simply as

> **during the night**

the difference being that **during the night** is a time interval without notion of **when exactly**.
**Over the course of the night** implies greater awareness about each passing moment

Comment: It's slang, but one could say, "This trip is an overnighter." For example: _This one is an overnighter so I won't be back until tomorrow afternoon._ (Neil Sorenson). As for _over the night_ vs. _during the night_, I agree with you there, but would like to mention that we can say "over the course of the night," too, particularly when talking about something that transpires over time. For example: _Watching the accumulating effects of a tripod sinking slowly into damp soil over the course of a night can be very frustrating_ (Grant Privett).

Answer (score 2):

The adjective overnight is an attributive adjective. So we can say 'this overnight trip".

However, the overnight in the sentencr 'this trip is overnight' isn't an adjective as it cannot be used as a predicative adjective that follows a linking verb. This sentence is grammatically correct; the overnight has been used as an adverb.

As for the sentence "it happened overnight", the sentence is correct; the overnight has been used as an adverb. But we don't hear people use " over the night". However, you can say "It happened for the night or during the  night.

Answer (score 1):

*Overnight* can be used as an adjective.

> We went on the overnight trip.

*To be* and some other verbs can take *subject complements* instead of objects - and adjectives can be subject complements.

> This trip is overnight.

*Overnight* can also be an adverb and directly modify a verb.

> It happened overnight.